# In AngularJS, how do I toggle a class on one element at a time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a set of elements in an app that I need to user to click one at a time and add an active class.

Normally I was do something like `ng-class="{'active':isActive}"` and use an `ng-click` event to toggle `$scope.isActive` between true and false. However, this I normally do this against a single item. If I do this against a group items then it will add an active class to all of them.

-- edit --

for a bit more detail i have a setup like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <button ng-click="setClass()">click</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <button ng-click="setClass()">click</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <button ng-click="setClass()">click</button>
</div>
```

I could use something like `ng-class="{'active':addClass}"` but that would trigger all the buttons to have the "active" class

Comment: When you click on one item does it need to have the active class removed from the previously active item?

Comment: Nope. Basically, the `ng-click` will set the element to "active" and trigger a database call to change a db value. Switching the db value I have figured out. The toggle however, not so much.

Comment: You could extend the object with an active property to each item, and use ng-class

Comment: All your buttons are sharing the same controller `$scope`, so when you set isActive it's of course applying to all of them.   You probably want each button to be a directive with isolate scope instead; then each one can have its own `scope.isActive` variable independent from the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Bind each button to its own object:

```
<div class="item" ng-class="{active: buttonOne.isActive}" ng-model="buttonOne">
  <button ng-click="setClass()">click</button>
</div>
<div class="item" ng-class="{active: buttonTwo.isActive}" ng-model="buttonTwo">
  <button ng-click="setClass()">click</button>
</div>
<div class="item" ng-class="{active: buttonThree.isActive}" ng-model="buttonThree">
  <button ng-click="setClass()">click</button>
</div>
```

This will cause them to get activated individually. This works really well in a `ng-repeat` so I'd suggest that you create your buttons this way if they're going to be fairly similar.